# When is a Java 8 Stream considered to be consumed?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

My understanding was that a Java 8 `Stream` is considered to be consumed once a terminal operation, such as `forEach()` or `count()`, is performed.

However, the test case `multipleFilters_separate` below throws an `IllegalStateException` even though `filter` is a lazy intermediate operation, just called as two statements. And yet, I can chain the two filter operations into a single statement and it works.

```
@Test(expected=IllegalStateException.class)
public void multipleFilters_separate() {
    Stream<Double> ints = Stream.of(1.1, 2.2, 3.3);
    ints.filter(d -> d > 1.3);
    ints.filter(d -> d > 2.3).forEach(System.out::println);
}

@Test
public void multipleFilters_piped() {
    Stream<Double> ints = Stream.of(1.1, 2.2, 3.3);
    ints.filter(d -> d > 1.3)
        .filter(d -> d > 2.3)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

From this, I'm assuming a `Stream` is considered to be consumed after the first statement that uses it whether that statement calls a terminal operation or not. Does that sound right?

Comment: `ints.filter(d -> d > 1.3);` does nothing.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A `Stream` is considered consumed once a terminal operation is executed. However, even multiple intermediate operations are not supposed to be executed for the same `Stream` instance, as stated in the `Stream` javadoc:

> A stream should be **operated on (invoking an intermediate or terminal stream operation) only once**. This rules out, for example, "forked" streams, where the same source feeds two or more pipelines, or multiple traversals of the same stream. **A stream implementation may throw IllegalStateException if it detects that the stream is being reused.** However, since some stream operations may return their receiver rather than a new stream object, it may not be possible to detect reuse in all cases.

In case of intermediate stream operations, you should call the next operation on the `Stream` returned by the previous operation:

```
public void multipleFilters_separate() {
    Stream<Double> ints = Stream.of(1.1, 2.2, 3.3);
    ints = ints.filter(d -> d > 1.3);
    ints.filter(d -> d > 2.3).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's the point the OP was trying to make, as it's clear that the two `filter` statements are meant to be redundant.

Comment: No, I intended to comment on what you say is the "correct way to write it".  I sense that a forked stream was the intended use case, not a chained stream as you've suggested.

Comment: @JoeC I'm not sure the OP intended a forked stream.

Comment: I wasn't intentionally thinking of a forked stream, just splitting out my operations into separate statements for readability and to add more detailed comments. But, doing this seems fraught with danger.

Comment: @craigcaulfield well, as I said, (if you are not chaining the calls) you have to keep a reference to the `Stream` returned by each `Stream` operation, and call the next operation on that new `Stream`.

Comment: As much as I find Streams a welcome and very powerful addition to the Java ecosystem, the fact that such important properties are described in English in the JavaDocs as opposed to being expressed as types in the type system, where they can be mechanically checked by the compiler, makes me sad.

Comment: @JörgWMittag The compiler can't check everything. There are many pre-Java 8 examples of JDK classes that throw runtime exceptions if you don't use them according to the Javadoc contracts. The closest example I can think of (to the Stream behavior covered in this question) is calling `Thread.start()` twice. The compiler doesn't stop you from doing that and the second call throws an exception.

Comment: Yes, and that's a shame. Personally, I don't use Java much, but people always tell me that I *should* be using Java, because it has interfaces and interface define the contract of an object and can be checked by the compiler and therefore, there can't be any errors, but every time I actually *try* to use Java, I find that the contracts are actually specified in JavaDocs and not in the interfaces, and are *not* checked by the compiler. For example: where does the `List` interface specify that `sort` sorts a list? Why doesn't the compiler complain, when I implement `List.add` as `return;`?

Comment: @JörgWMittag I don't think it is possible to create a language that is capable to enforce all possible contracts at compile time. It may be easy for the compiler to check that `sort` does not simply `return;`, but how far exactly should it go in verifying that the algorithm actually yields a list that is sorted correctly? As it is not possible to check everything, it is a question of tradeoffs - other languages draw the line at different places, but I'm sure that there is no useful language in which it is true that there "can't be any errors" at runtime.

Comment: @Hulk: For example, in Idris, Epigram, Guru, Coq, Isabelle (and probably many others I forgot), it is possible to encode *any* statement that can be encoded in (some system of) logic as a type and have it statically checked by the compiler. A statement like "forall consecutive pairs `(a, b)` of elements of a list, `a <= b` must be true" can be encoded in the return type of `sort`, and an implementation that doesn't satisfy this condition won't compile.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Interesting - I did not know any of them. Does any of these languages support mutable state? I seems that this kind of proofing correctness is easier when Objects are immutable - also, they all seem to follow the functional paradigm rather than an imperative approach.

Answer (score 12):

According to the [`Stream` Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html):

> A stream should be operated on (invoking an intermediate or terminal stream operation) only once. This rules out, for example, "forked" streams, where the same source feeds two or more pipelines, or multiple traversals of the same stream. A stream implementation may throw `IllegalStateException` if it detects that the stream is being reused. However, since some stream operations may return their receiver rather than a new stream object, it may not be possible to detect reuse in all cases.

In your case, the call to `filter` itself is detecting an attempt to fork your stream into two different streams.  Rather than wait and cause problems once the terminal operation is added, it's performing a pre-emptive strike to make it clear from any stack trace you get exactly where your problem is.